# c# SqlDataReader repeating final row of data

Tags: c#, sql, while-loop, sqldatareader

I'm using an SqlDataReader to read to a  collection of custom type , but all I'm getting is the final row of the DataTable repeated, rather than a full table of information. Help would be gratefully received.

```
using (connection)
        {

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        lineData.Column1 = reader.GetValue(0).ToString();
                        lineData.Column2 = reader.GetValue(1).ToString();
                        lineData.Column3 = reader.GetValue(2).ToString();
                        lineData.Column4 = reader.GetValue(3).ToString();
                        lineData.Column5 = reader.GetValue(4).ToString();
                        lineData.Column6 = reader.GetValue(5).ToString();
                        lineData.Column7 = reader.GetValue(6).ToString();
                        lineData.Column8 = reader.GetValue(7).ToString();
                        columnData.Add(lineData);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

 foreach (var item in columnData)
        {
            Label.Text += item.Column1.ToString() + item.Column2.ToString() + item.Column3.ToString() + item.Column7.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: the code seems to be fine... can you upload your results(such as screen shots). and where did you declare `columnData` and why outside the loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lineData` should be declared within while loop. If it was declared before the code you uploaded, then you're referencing the same instance for every data row.
Try change code to following;

```
while (reader.Read())
                {
                    lineData = new LineData();//like that
```

Comment: Knew it was something dumb. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

lineData must be declared during the cycle at that time. If it is declared before the code you uploaded, you to the same instance for each row of data. Try to change the code on the following;